# Cancel infinite loop execution in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, infinite-loop, jsfiddle

When you get an infinite loop in jsfiddle in Chrome, your only choice (that I know of) is to close the tab.  Of course, this means you lose all your work in the current window!  Is there an easy way to stop an infinitely executing script?

1. I have the developer tools open because I was doing some debugging.
2. I am able to pause the script and step through the loop.
3. I can't find anywhere to stop the script.
4. I can't modify the script or variables to stop the infinite loop (because the script execution occurs in an iframe on a separate domain, so modifying data in the iframe with JavaScript is not allowed and generates an Exception in the console).

It all started because I decided to swap directions on my loop from

```
for (var c = 0; c <= 11; c++)
```

to

```
for (var c = 12; c > 0; c++)
```

But as you can see above, I forgot to change it from `c++` to `c--`.

Any ideas??  I still have the tab open and I'm hoping to get it back without closing the tab :-)

Comment: Can't you change the value of c in the debugger?

Comment: Firefox detects infinite loops and stops them

Comment: Chrome should eventually ask you if you want to kill the script if you let it go.

Comment: @ryudice Nice to know, but that doesn't help him. I've just replicated an infinite loop, and haven't found a way to get in between. Still trying.

Comment: @methodin: It's been running for about 10 minutes (c = `9494127`) and it still hasn't asked me if I want to stop the script.  Do I have to leave focus on that window for awhile first?  EDIT: I got the popup, but the only choice is to `Kill Pages`, not stop the script.  That will lose all my data.

Comment: Hmm. What's with the random downvote after almost a year?

Comment: As you have commented in an answer below, I'm glad you were lucky to have dev tools open and were able to recover your code. But if that were not the case, wouldn't **`"c"`** eventually wrap around to **`"0"`** (or overflow) and then exit the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the developer mode, go into resources and find your script and copy and paste it into a text document or a new window. If you can't find it in resources, do a search for a variable or line of code you used.

Comment: If he doesn't have the dev tab open he might be screwed. The page died for me when I attempted it.

Comment: He said he has it open though

Comment: @Walkerneo: Brilliant!  Duh, just copy the script out and paste it somewhere else... lol  Got it, thanks!  Also need to copy the html/css code if applicable.  It still would be nice to know as well if there's a way to get there if you don't already have the developer console open.  You might just be screwed if that happens.

Comment: I got it to open but it fails to load any html/javascript/css/anything.  Breakpoints don't work either :\

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have it open you're royally screwed.

Comment: You can try to select all the page (Ctrl+A) and copy it, then you can close the tab. It's not very practical, but it can save your work.

Answer (score 100):

How to do it without Developer Mode:

- Open a new tab
- Open the Task Manager with Shift-Escape
- Kill task
- **Use back button for the killed tab** (JSFiddle won't run the script)
- Fix bug
- Update

Or on MacOS,

- Open Activity Monitor
- Kill the first "Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)" process. It's probably JSFiddle
- Fix the issue
- Run the code

Comment: This is a much better answer

Comment: worked for me thanks, i did lose my last edit though, so maybe this method isn't for everyone

Comment: @Adam Ritter: This worked for me. Thanks so much for posting ... this was a lifesaver.

Comment: In Chrome this will take you to your previous version / last update. :(

Comment: @Luke What do you mean? This answer is amazing!

Comment: This didn't work for me in Chrome — JSFiddle executed the code again. I'll post my answer...

Comment: worked for me.. found this while my loop was spinning.  trick for me was to find right task to kill.. but yep.  some blue screen occupied the browser window, browser back reloaded my code. Be nice if there could be an easier way, but js fiddle and chrome are both awesome, so no complaints just wishes.

Comment: it amazing thank a lot ritter i want this method for long time

Comment: It would be nice if - like in the good ol' days - you could just press CTRL-C or something in the console.

Comment: @ADAM Hey man.. really thanks. your suggestion saved me nearly a day work from a simple infinite call issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

One way of breaking the infinite loop is to throw an unhandled exception, which will stop the execution of current call stack.
To do so:

1. pause the debbuger
2. find a promising statement inside the loop, for example a function call: `foo.bar(args)`
3. in console, overwrite the function to throw : `foo.bar=function(){throw 42;}`
4. unpause the debugger

worked for me. I haven't tried, but I believe that by overloading getter or setter you can use the trick described above also for assignments and reads, not only for function calls. Also, by setting a variable to undefined, you may cause fatal error (and thus break the loop) if the field of this variable is used in the loop. For example `delete foo.tab` will break `foo.tab[42]` or `foo.tab.bar`. For some reason, simply writting `foo=undefined` in the console, will not do (perhaps it defines a variable local to the console window named foo).

Comment: I can't seem to change any variable values while paused in the middle of an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

Run Process Explorer and kill the chrome process that's using lots of CPU...it will "crash" the page and let you reload...

Comment: Killing the process wasn't the issue.  I didn't want to lose my current script.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't start Chrome's Task Manager while the looping tab was active. I had to select another tab. Then I pressed Shift-Escape to launch the Task Manager, kill the JSFiddle process, re-select the tab, and hit the back button to display the page without running the script.

JSFiddle loads the "result" panel using an iframe. As of June 2016, the URL for the frame is the Fiddle URL plus "/show/". I inspected the source code of the iframe and discovered that it loads yet another URL with "/light/". One of these URLs should contain your source code.

If your browser supports the [view-source URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme), you may access your fiddle's source code as follows:

- view-source:jsfiddle.net/user_name/fiddle_hash/revision/light/
- view-source:jsfiddle.net/user_name/fiddle_hash/revision/show/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem came up here, I opened up the javascript console in a script paused state. (Paused it using the Developer Tools)

Then I changed the variable value so that the while loop would end.

Comment: To make it clear, the variable which was used in the while loop condition which I had forgotten to change. I changed that through the console and the loop ended.

Comment: That is correct, you can change the variable value to end the loop.  That's the very first thing I thought of as well.  However, in my particular case (using jsfiddle), the executing script runs in a different domain in a subframe from the main page, so you can't modify the variable values in the frame, which causes the problem :)

Comment: @mellamokb except changing the variable value doesn't work! it appears to set it, but when you read it back it's back to the old value.  ARGH!

Answer (score 0):

In case others are stuck after reading the other answers, here's what worked for me (Chrome, Mac). For me the JSFiddle tab was 'stuck' but the rest of Chrome responsive. I had the JavaScript Console open on the Resources pane, but it was unresponsive too. Reloading the page in this state didn't help because JSFiddle would give me the script before I got anything at all.

In the end this worked for me; maybe it will help you too...

- While the page is unresponsive, go to `Chrome > Preferences > Privacy` and disable JavaScript.
- Wait for page to die (about 4 or 5 minutes for me); the sad face icon comes up in that tab.
- Hit the back button. It should look like JSFiddle is loading, but it won't because funnily enough JSFiddle needs JavaScript just to render a page.
- `View > Developer > View source`
- My script, only slightly mangled, was sitting there all innocent like in a `div` called `'panel_js'`.
- Highlight, copy, breathe again, learn lesson.

Answer (score 0):

I had file stuck in a loop and would freeze up the dashboard on JSFiddle as well.

- The only way I could clear was to disable JavaScript in the preferences tab while I had a New Fiddle page open in a different Chrome tab.
- Then navigate to All Fiddles.
- Delete the Fiddle and then it would give a 404 error.
- Turn on the JavaScript and reload the Dashboard.
- Was able to continue on making and editing fiddles after that.