# How to recover unsaved JS changes in JSFiddle with infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, infinite-loop, jsfiddle

I accidentally created an infinite loop in JSFiddle, so the page is unresponsive. I haven't saved in a while, so I don't want to reload and lose changes. I'm using Chrome, but it's been twenty minutes and Chrome hasn't yet caught the loop and given me a chance to end the script.

I do have the developer console open, but it isn't very responsive. Does Chrome have a local copy of my code somewhere on the hard drive?

Comment: See also: [Cancel infinite loop execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616143/cancel-infinite-loop-execution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me: I clicked on a bookmark to go forward, and leave the page. Then I was able to hit the back button and it retained everything for me. If I had refreshed or killed the page I would have lost everything. If you don't have a bookmark bar (and clicking on links in the page doesn't work because it's stuck) you might try adding a URL to the address bar to go *forward* a page, then you can go back.

Comment: This did not work for me. I was able to kill the tab, hit the back button, then the forward button to get my most recent content again, but my page almost instantly hit the infinite loop again. I'm finding the inability to salvage your work is a major shortcoming for jsfiddle.

Comment: Phew! This saved me from losing my hard hours of headaches... Great advice :)