# Stop JavaScript without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some JavaScript that, I believe, is stuck in an infinite loop. I know I can just reload the page, but I have data in a form on the current page that I'd like to keep. The tab is completely unresponsive, so I can't just copy and paste everything and then reload. So is there any way to kill the javascript thread, but keep the DOM in Chrome?

Comment: "Is there any way to kill the javascript thread, but keep the DOM in Chrome?" Nope. You just got to fix your infinite loop.

Comment: After thirty seconds Chrome gives you the chance to stop the executing script. You can recover the information then.

Comment: Here's the painful issue... The infinite loop is in a codepen.io pen. So if I reload, I lose a lot of the code that actually caused the infinite loop.

Comment: As @BCartolo mentioned, you should get a prompt to kill it. If not, I guess take a screen shot and capture as much of the code as you can...

Comment: If you are writing lots of things on the web it's a good idea to use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno

Comment: An advice, program in your IDE, SublimeText, Atom, VSCode, and then use online tool to test your code, that way you lose less time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the developer console <kbd>F12</kbd> and stop the script[image]

Comment: You can't stop the script, but you can pause it and inspect the DOM.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You can stop the script - just click on the *Pause* button, then click-and-hold on the *Play* button and choose *Stop* from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 3):

Open chrome developer tools and go to the sources tab. On the right panel press "pause script execution".

[image]

Comment: Then click-and-hold on the *Play* button and choose *Stop* from the drop-down menu in order to stop the script execution.

Comment: @nuitech - how do you click Stop when mouse is already on click-and-hold, the moment you release it to stop the execution it doesn't work, why is there no stop button, i mean really now?

Answer (score 1):

looks like someone had the same problem

[Cancel infinite loop execution in jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616143/cancel-infinite-loop-execution-in-jsfiddle)

Answer:

> With the developer mode, go into resources and find your script and copy and paste it into a text document or a new window. If you can't find it in resources, do a search for a variable or line of code you used.